# Explain excel formula in PRD

Tags: java, excel

I have an excel template which needs to be automated by the developer using JAVA, the problem here is that the developer is not well versed with excel and want all excel formula in detail in PRD document.

It would be great if anyone can guide me here to how to explain excel formula most effectively in PRD document or is there any other better option to explain all the details in excel as well.

Comment: Please add more details on what the relationship is here between Java and Excel.  If the developer is already controlling some of the worksheet from Java, then perhaps he should be the one who owns the formulas.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: The developer needs to automate the excel template on the dashboard using JAVA, and he needs to replicate all the excel formulas at backend.

Comment: Just give him the mathematical formula for the task and let them program it from scratch.

Comment: @SolarMike: How can i explain this formula `=IFERROR(IF(OR(C4>D4,C4>0),(D4-C4)/C4,-(D4-C4)/C4)," ")` in mathematical or programming terms.

Comment: What is the variable in cell C4? what is the variable in cell D4? So if D4 is Revenue and C4 is cost, then you could well say if the cost exceeds the revenue then revenue-Cost which is profit / cost etc, but without knowing exactly what you are achieving my suggestion stands.

Comment: @SolarMike: Suppose Its revenue in `C4` for previous year and in `D4` for current year.

Comment: So, how would you explain those values in accounting terms...

Comment: @SolarMike: I would explain it as a growth.

Comment: Only if current year is better than last year...

Comment: @SolarMike: Yes i guess

Answer (score 0):

There are very many examples (though a minority!) here on SO of how to "explain" an Excel formula. The essence of the process is:

- work from the inside out
- apply Evaluate Formula (from the Formula Auditing tab)
- refer to `https://support.office.com` for details function by function

For *presentation* judicious use of <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> can be very helpful where formulae are complex - to insert line breaks to split logical components.

(The above are also the main steps in debugging issues with a formula, though for that some overwriting of data is also often very helpful - so reliance is not on what *seems* to be the data but what is *known* to be, particularly for format, precision and spaces.)